# In .NET, DbGeography.PointFromText is throwing a Not Implemented exception, when it should be implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

So I'm trying to do some simple `Geography` stuff in an old `.NET 4.6.2` project. I have `EF 5` installed (not planning on upgrading to `EF 6`).

When I try and do some simple `DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT 1 1", 4326);` I get a `Not Implemented Exception` thrown.

e.g.

```
SqlServerTypes.Utilities.LoadNativeAssemblies (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
var xxx = System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(1 1)", 4326);
```

[image]

I thought `EF 5` has this method in it and it's totally ok to use? (e.g. reference material about using `DbGeograpghy`).

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible the wrong (old?) dll is getting used and therefore, thrown?

#### Update 1 (Possibly not a duplicate).

It was suggested that the issue is because `DbGeography` requires (from nuget) `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` package. So I tried installing that from nuget, then making sure I 'load' these special dll's at the start of my test. Problem still existed.

#### Update 2

Using [NuGet Microsoft.SqlServer.Types version 14.0.314.76 (current version as of the time of this post)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types/)